# How to make adwords autobidding bid separately on each keyword

Tags: advertising, google-ads, campaigns

I used manual bidding most of the times I worked with Adwords, but recently I encountered client with 4000+ keywords. I tried automatic bidding to save my time, but it does work in weird way.

It sets automatic price for every keywords in WHOLE campaign to the same price. So normally, there is usually few hundred keywords in campaign, some of them expensive, some of them cheap. But when I turn the automatic bidding on, it takes the most expensive keyword and sets all the keywords in campaign to that price. As a result, almost all of the keywords are ridiculously overpriced with average position of 1,0 or 1,1.

Is there a way to set up automatic bids so that it calculates them for each keyword separately?